# Is it possible to deploy Visual Studio Coded UI Tests to Azure or EC2 as Test Agents?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, selenium-grid, smoke-testing

I'm not that entirely familiar with the testing suite that comes with Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate) but I'm trying to find a means to produce something similar to [Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/) with the Coded UI Tests. I'd like to be able to deploy agents to Azure or EC2, execute all Coded UI tests, and then tear them down for a smoke test as part of a deployment process.

From what I am seeing around the net, its possible to do something similiar to this via controllers and agents but I'm not certain how much of that can be easily migrated to the cloud. Ive found these posts: [Load Testing with Agents running on Windows Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricardo/archive/2011/04/08/load-testing-with-agents-running-on-windows-azure-part-1.aspx): [[1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricardo/archive/2011/04/08/load-testing-with-agents-running-on-windows-azure-part-1.aspx) [2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricardo/archive/2011/04/08/load-testing-with-agents-running-on-windows-azure-part-2.aspx) [3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricardo/archive/2011/04/08/load-testing-with-agents-running-on-windows-azure-part-3.aspx)] but they surround load testing. It is my understanding that load tests can compiled and easily deployed but that is not necessarily the case for Coded UI tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if its possible but i do know a little about the agents. Agents allow you to connect to the machine and deploy a test to it. I think as long as your controller can access that VM then it should be ok. I believe you can set up Azure so their will be an external name for the VM.

The same process should work for coded ui tests as well. they are also deployed using agents and controllers

Comment: I'm no longer on that project and will not be attempting this so I can't test. I am going to mark this as an answer unless someone says otherwise. 

Thanks for taking the time to respond.